# html tags show up in json data angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am busy making an app in Ionic and I am running into a problem with a JSON string that contains HTML.. The JSON is getting pulled off a Joomla site and seems to be retaining the HTML tags and special chars.. The string looks like this: `"&lt;div&gt;Apple aims to have its smart watch on wrists in China`

I looked around and found that I should use ng-bind-html but that only outputs the actual tags as strings like this: `<div>Apple aims to have its smart watch on wrists in China`

Is there any way to either get rid of the HTML altogether or to escape it maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the HTML text through `.replace` to get rid of the tags

```
var yourstring = "&lt;div&gt;Your text content&lt;/div&gt;";
yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&lt;[^&]*&gt;/g, '');
// yourstring is now "Your text content"
```